# Is numpy variable link with each other ?(help)

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a file like this:

```
import numpy as np
rx = np.zeros((2,2))
rx2 = rx
rx2[0][1]=1
print(rx)
print(rx2)
```

Expected result were:

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

But when I ran this code, I got:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Why and how?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
rx = np.zeros((2,2))
rx2 = rx.copy()
rx2[0][1]=1
print(rx)
print(rx2)
```

results in

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Actually `rx2` isn't even a copy.  The variable references the same array object as `rx`.  With (non-object dtype) arrays there isn't a difference between shallow copy and deep copy.

Comment: @hpaulj, you are correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, any reference that you use copy instead of normal assign?